# Параллельный столбик в цикле for для java

Tags: java, for

```
Первый фор выводит 
х0
х1
х3
.
.
Не могу понять как сделать 
х0 у0
х1 у1
х2 у2
public  static void table(double a,double b,double n){
        double h = (b-a)/n;
        int count =0;
        double sum=0;
        int count2=0;
        for (double x=a;x<=b;x=x+h){
            System.out.println("x"+count+"="+x);
            count=count+1;
                       }
          for (double y1=a;y1<=b:y1=y1+h){
            System.out.print("у"+count2+"="+f(y1));
            count2=count2+1;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно тот вывод, что вы привели? Перепроверьте, а то может опять ошиблись

Comment: нужно два столбика один просто х второй это у от функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно на промежутке от `a` до `b` получить значения функции `f(x)` если это так, то вам не нужен вложенный цикл.

Вывод должен быть примерно таким:

```
for (double x = a; x <= b; x = x + h) {
    System.out.println("x" + count + "=" + x + "  y" + count + "=" + f(x));
    count = count + 1;
}
```

Comment: понял спасибо !!!

Comment: @Mobsman если вам помог мой ответ, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" :)